# grep command to find the value of key from json

Tags: linux

Please explain how to use grep command to extract some specified text from  the following json -

```
{"result":"Customer information saved successfully with Customer id :59 and version :1","status":{"responseCode":200,"result":null,"responseMessage":"Success","responseType":"info"}}
```

After some googling, it looks like it is possible by using grep with a regular expression. But it is not working. Can you please point out the mistake

```
cat response.txt | grep -Po '(?<="Customer id ":)[0-9]+'
```

Assumption: response.txt contains the above json.

If yes please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you missed `K`:

```
cat response.txt | grep -Po 'Customer id :\K[0-9]+'
59
```

screenshot, its working:
[image]

Comment: grep can read files on it's own, so `grep ... file` (useless use of cat). And the `\K` is a shorthand for what the OP use already, positive look-behind

Comment: it is working....i  had missed some text...Can u please explain it in details ..or can u give a link where can i find the detail documentation regarding it .

Comment: Can you explain what K does here?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$ jq -r '.result' json_file | grep -oP '(?<=Customer id :)\d+'
59
```

Check http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: I am aware of jq tool , but our server does not have jq tool installed . I have no other option than to use grep command . Is it possible ?

Comment: jq can be downloaded as user and executed directly without any dependencies